# Copying a filtered data from a table set and paste it on the next empty row of another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I tried to copy a set of filtered data from the worksheet "PEP" (Filter: Emetteurs, in column 18) and paste it in the next empty row in the worksheet"Sanctions". I found this text code online and add the section NextRow in order to paste it on the next Empty Row in the "Sanctions" Worksheet. I just started using VBA not long ago, so I tried to use codes online however in this case, I think the problem here is that I cannot define the value of range. I tried to look it up online but no result. Thank you in advance for all your help!

```
Dim k,j,i As Interger
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sanctions").Select
NextRow=Cells(Range("A"&Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row+1,1

k=1
With sheets("PEP")
 T=.Range("A1:AS"&.Cells(Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Row)
 .Rows(1).Copy Sheets("Sanctions").Range("NextRow")
End With

For i=2 To UBound(T,1)
 If T(i,18)="Emetteurs" Then
   k=k+1
   For j =1 to UBound(T,2)
    T(k,j)=T(i,j)
   Next j 
 End If

Next i
With Sheets("Sanctions")
 Application.ScreenUpdating=False
 .Range("NextRow").Resiwe(k,UBound(T,2))=T.Offset(1)
 .Columns.AutoFit
 Application.ScreenUpdating=True
End With
End Sub
```

And if possible I would also like to find a solution to remove the header once I do the Copy-Paste process.

Comment: Note that `Dim k,j,i As Interger` defines `i As Integer` bit `k` and `j` as `Variant`. In VBA you need to specify a type for **every** variable, otherwise it is `Variant` by default. Also they must be of type `Long` because Excel has more rows than `Integer` can handle: `Dim k As Long, j As Long, i As Long`. Since [there is no benefit in using `Integer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409117/why-use-integer-instead-of-long/26409520#26409520)  I recommend always to use `Long` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the code's comments and adjust it to fit your needs.

Some things to begin:

1. Use [option explicit](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html) so you don't have unexpected behavior with undefined variables
2. Always indent your code (see [www.rubberduckvba.com](http://www.rubberduckvba.com) a free tool that helps you with that)
3. Try to separate your logic defining variables and the reusing them

---

**EDIT:** Some reviews to your code:

1. As mentioned by @Pᴇʜ you need to declare each of your variables types.

   This:

   > ```
   > Dim k,j,i As Interger
   > ```

   is the same as declaring:

   ```
   Dim k As Variant
   Dim j As Variant
   Dim i As Integer
   ```

   **Side note.** You had a typo in `Interger`

   Which is not what you really want, knowing that all of them are going to store numbers

---

2. Declare the objects that you're going to work with. For example, you refer to the sheet Sanctions three times in your code:

   > ```
   > ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sanctions")
   > ```

   This can be set once like this:

   ```
   Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sanctions")
   ```

   And then reused in lines like this:

   > ```
   > With Sheets("Sanctions")
   > ```

   or this:

   > ```
   > Sheets("Sanctions").Range("NextRow")
   > ```

   by writing this:

   ```
   With targetSheet
   ```

   in this way, if you ever need to change it (the person working with your code, or your future you will be really thankful)

---

3. Declaring your variables to just letters, makes your code really hard to understand.

   > ```
   > Dim j,k,l
   > ```

   is different when you have:

   ```
   Dim lastRow As Long
   Dim lastColumn As Long
   etc.
   ```

---

I suggest that you use the key `F8` and step through the code, and see the logic behind it. That way you can learn more.

---

**Code:**

```
Public Sub ConditionalRowCopy()

    ' Declare object variables
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range

    ' Declare other variables
    Dim sourceLastRow As Long
    Dim targetLastRow As Long

    ' Set a reference to the sheets so you can access them later
    Set sourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PEP")
    Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sanctions")

    ' Find last row in source sheet based on column "R"
    sourceLastRow = sourceSheet.Cells(sourceSheet.Rows.Count, "R").End(xlUp).Row

    ' Find cell with word "Emetteurs", search in column R)
    For Each cell In sourceSheet.Range("R1:R" & sourceLastRow).Cells

        ' If match
        If cell.Value = "Emetteurs" Then
            ' Find last row in target sheet based on column "A"
            targetLastRow = targetSheet.Cells(targetSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            ' Copy entire row to next empty row in target sheet
            cell.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=targetSheet.Range("A" & targetLastRow).Offset(RowOffset:=1)
        End If

    Next cell

End Sub
```

Let me know if it works!

Comment: It worked magnificently! Thank you. Can you tell me where I was wrong?

Comment: thank you! I see my errors, I will learn a lot from this! Thanks again for your help!

Comment: This answer has valuable advice for a new programmer, and has saved a confused question from being possibly closed.